# What is the correct syntax in Tampermonkey to point to a local audio file?

Tags: html5-audio, tampermonkey

I would like to play a local audio file (mp3) with the help of the HTML5 [audio controls](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) element. The element itself appears and the inspected source code looks fine.

But whatever I try, I don't find the correct syntax for the complete path to this local audio file on my Windows 10 environment:

```
C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\T1\Example Path\Lucky Me\2022\01 - What's with spaces and aphostrophes.mp3
```

Inside Tampermonkey I tried it with two and three forward slashes after `file:`, with double backslashes between the directories and subdirectores, with a slash to escape the apostrophe, but nothing works. The HTML element on the webbpage remains greyed out - indicating that it can't find/access the above audio file.

The code snippet so far:

```
var sound = document.createElement("audio");

sound.id = "MyAudioPlayer";
sound.controls = "controls";
sound.src = "file://C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\T1\Example Path\Lucky Me\2022\01 - What's with spaces and aphostrophes.mp3";    
sound.type = "audio/mpeg";
```

If I copy paste the URL from the inspected element directly into the address bar from Google Chrome, the file will be found and played without any problem.

What can I do?

**Update:**
It seems to be an access problem. Thanks to @wOxxOm I found this errors in the Google Chrome devtools (<kbd>F12</kbd>).
What I don't get: If I copy & paste the same path `file:///C:/Temp/Test.mp3` into the browser adress bar and press enter, the file is accessible and plays fine.
[image]

None of the commandline start options like `--disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access` seems to make any difference.

**How can I get my browser to accept locally stored files without copy or move all the existing audio files to a local webserver?**

Comment: Open chrome://extensions, click Details for Tampermonkey and allow file access there.

Comment: "File access" ("Zugriff auf Datei-URLs zulassen") is allowed. I have also restartet Google Chrome and reloaded the page. Still doesn't work. **BUT:** If I save the complete webpage to a local folder, the HTML5 audio element works fine. So I assume it has to do with access rights. Are there some more restrictions I have to disable? Maybe inside Tampermonkey?

Comment: Yes, `Allow scripts to access local files` in Tampermonkey options.

Comment: Thanks for your hints @wOxxOm . Unfortunately, also the Tampermonkey setting "Allow scripts to access local files: All local files" is still not enough. The control remains greyed out. (In the meantime I tried it with a much easier path like `C:\temp\test.mp3` - no difference). Any other ideas?

Comment: Open devtools for the page and see if there's an error. I guess Chrome may be blocking file URLs on web pages intentionally.

Comment: You are right: "Not allowed to load local resource" appears in devtools, even with the additional chrome start parameter ` --allow-file-access-from-file`. How can I disable this restriction? Or do you know other browser without this limitation?

Comment: Use a local http server and access the file via `http://localhost`